# Best practice for adding to a pull request on your repository?

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

I have a repository that someone has submitted pull request to, where forked my repo quite a few commits ago. I've cloned his pull request and was playing around with it and fixed some errors in his commit. What is the best way to add my own commits on top of his? I don't want to merge his pull request without applying the fixes first.

My immediate thoughts are:

- clone his fork, commit locally and submit a PR to his fork. He would then merge my changes into his pull request which I would then merge.
- create a new branch in my repo, make it point to the commit he forked from, merge his PR in this new branch, add my commits until I'm satisfied and merge new branch back to master.

So far I have tried the second one, but when I git pull my network graph (viewed on github) goes from

```
owner        --.--.--.--.--.--.| master
               |
PR submitter   .--.| PR commit
```

to

```
owner        --.--.--.--.--.--.|master
               |
               .--.| new-branch
```

and it seems like he loses authorship. I don't his contribution to be erased if I later merge new-branch into master. What is the best option? are there others I haven't thought about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach is perfectly fine. Add your commits, then merge to master.

Authorship is not shown in the github network graph like this. When you hover over commits, you see owner.